# Rearranging Conditional Probability Equation to Show Dependencies

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

Given the random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, with joint pdf given by $p(x,y,z)=kf(x,z)g(y,z)h(z)$ for some constant $k$, my task is to show that $p(x|y,z)$ is a function of $x$ and $z$. My work is as follows:

$$p(x|y,z)=\frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(y,z)}=\frac{kf(x,z)g(y,z)h(z)}{g(y,z)h(z)}=kf(x,z). $$

I'm not sure if this is correct, or honestly how to make sense of this question. Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: In general, you can't say that $p(x|y,z)$ is a function of $x, z$ only. Does your joint pdf have some form?

Comment: Made some edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we marginalize and find $p_{Y,Z}(y,z)$, assuming continuous RVs without loss of generality since in discrete case, the expression transforms into a summation rather than integration: $$p_{Y,Z}(y,z)=\int k f(x,z)g(y,z)h(z)dx=kg(y,z)h(z)\underbrace{\int f(x,z)dx}_{m(z)}$$
Then, we substitute into the original conditional density formula:
$$p_{X|Y,Z}(x|y,z)=\frac{p(x,y,z)}{p(y,z)}=\frac{kf(x,z)g(y,z)h(z)}{kg(y,z)h(z)m(z)}=\frac{f(x,z)}{m(z)}$$
which means $p_{X|Y,Z}(x|y,z)$ is a function of $x$ and $z$.

A note on notation abuses: Normally, $p(x,y,z), p(y,z)$ etc. are not well written, since we use the same letter for different functions with different parameters. Correct way to write them is using subscripts denoting the RVs.